# syntax error 'select a,b,c,d,e,f from'

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO abc
VALUES (

a, b, c, d, e, f
)
SELECT a, b, c, d, e,f
FROM bcd
```

when i execute this iam getting synatx errors .how do i  get rid of the synatx error

Comment: Please provide the actual code that is causing the error.  Your code, as written, is incorrect, but having the real code causing the real error will be helpful in showing you what's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Are you thinking this?

```
INSERT INTO abc(a,b,c,d,e,f) SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f from bcd;
```

Answer (score 7):

the problem is you don't use the VALUES keyword when using a select statement to populate the values.

```
INSERT INTO abc (a,b,c,d,e,f) SELECT a, b, c, d, e,f FROM bcd
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) is a reference for the INSERT syntax

Comment: ya, seems to always be the case, which is a good thing, means there is a lot of knowledgeable people that use this site.

Comment: Yeah, I love this site for that exact reason.  That little bit of competition just adds to the fun.

Answer (score 0):

Here a,b,c,d,e,f are values or field names?

if they are values,

It will be: INSERT INTO abc VALUES('a','b','c','d','e','f');

If they are fields, you have to specify values to insert.

SELECT is ok, if they are fields.